# Convert Oracle to T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Сan you help me to convert this `Oracle` rule to `T-SQL`.

```
SELECT CAST(SYS_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'AccessSubject') AS NVARCHAR2(255)) AS AccessSubjectCode FROM DUAL
```

I would like to know how this will be in `T-SQL : SYS_CONTEXT()`

Comment: I think it would help if you were to explain what you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SYS_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'AccessSubject') call returns a value configured by the client application. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG98209 for details.

The most similar feature in SQL Server is the CONTEXT_INFO() function. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx. However, in SQL Server the context can store just a single value, of maximum 128 bytes (as opposed to Oracle, where there are multiple contexts and you can store multiple named values in each context).